# Call external function but no value

Tags: swift, macos

good morning,

i have this class:

```
import Cocoa

class PopOverDetails: NSViewController {

    var dID = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: NSTextField!

    public func fillDetails (ID:NSManagedObjectID) {

        print("=== fillDetails ===")
        print(ID)
        dID = "\(ID)"

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("=== viewDidLoad ===")
        print(dID)
    }

}
```

i call the function from another view controller

```
let Controller = PopOverDetails()
Controller.fillDetails(ID: list[0].objectID)
```

al works fine, but the problem is:
in my function fillDetails, i get the objectID Value which i "send" from the view controller.

but i can't work with this value in the viedidload because it is empty.
this is my output:

```
=== fillDetails ===
0x40000b <x-coredata://7E006435-3E05-41F9-A3E4-CB8179A319A9/list/p1>
=== viewDidLoad ===
```

where is my mistake? :)

**UPDATE**

```
let vcDetails = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "PopoverDetails") as! NSViewController
popover.contentViewController = vcDetails
popover.show(relativeTo: tblView.rect(ofRow: tblView.selectedRow) ,  of: tblView, preferredEdge: .maxX)
    }
```

Comment: The default initializer `PopOverDetails()` creates a new instance of the controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard / xib. You need the actual reference via a segue of `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 1):

First declare variable in PopOverDetails i.e."id",then

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your_identifier") as! PopOverDetails
secondViewController.id = list[0].objectID
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Now you can get that variable in PopViewController's class

Comment: sry but nothing of them works. perhaps i do it wrong.
i updated my first post with the code, which shows the popover from the first view controller